# What noun describes a redundant phrase like "temporary pause"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The phrase

> temporary pause

is unnecessarily long; just 'pause' is enough.

Does a *simple noun* exist to use to describe this type of usage?  'Redundant' or 'wordy' are good adjectives but I can't think of a good simple noun. (suggesting 'redundant usage' isn't what I'm looking for).  I'm looking for something analogous to 'oxymoron' but as it relates to the redundancy of the phrase.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Redundancy? ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 75 cent word you are looking for is

> **pleonasm**

[the use of more words than are necessary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pleonasm).

Answer (score 8):

It's an example of [tautology](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tautology)

> (Linguistics / Grammar) use of words that merely repeat elements of the meaning already conveyed, as in the sentence *Will these supplies be adequate enough?* in place of *Will these supplies be adequate?*

It's also *redundancy*, but that word has many other meanings beyond this specific sense. And *pleonasm* - [far less common overall](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pleonasm,tautology&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and often occurs as [pleonastic](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pleonasm,pleonastic&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (referring to longer texts, or to people who habitually write in this way).

Answer (score 4):

I would just call it a *redundancy*.  According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redundancy):

> *noun*
>   **2.** superfluous repetition or overlapping, especially of words.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but [turgid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turgid) can be used to describe language that is unnecessarily complex or bloated.