# Value (in cents) of big words

Tags: idioms, expressions

I found the answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45671/what-would-you-call-the-phrase-temporary-pause) interesting in that he referred to a "75 cent word". I would have called it a *50*-cent word, not because I undervalued his answer but because that is how I have heard the phrase. I thought at first that am old enough that inflation caused the difference, but  I found a 1976 reference to 75-cent word from 1976, the earliest reference to the phrase I found in a quick ngrams search.

What is the "right" value to use in the phrase "?-cent word" (or, what was the original)? Has it changed over time? Do non-American English speakers have alternative expressions in local currency?

Comment: This phrase also jumped out at me. I'd have called it a "5-dollar word" or an "SAT word", i.e. a word that sounds impressive but isn't terribly necessary.

Comment: Perhaps it increases along with inflation? My mom used to say 25-cent word.

Comment: Never heard of it. What does it mean, regardless of the number of cents involved?

Comment: The phrase can be found in books: http://www.google.com/search?q=75+cent+word&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%2275+cent+word%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=g_ueTpeGHqeA4gSXr5mhCQ&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=aff5e50bd73009ef&biw=1291&bih=720 ; not too many occurrences, but the meaning is consistent

Comment: It means that it is good for showing off one's vocabulary, @BarrieEngland. The word in question was pleonasm, by the way.

Comment: I don't think there is a non-US equivalent. I was unsure what was meant by a 75 cent word, because without any experience of the phrase, I didn't know whether that was to be valued high or low.

Comment: I've heard "five-dollar word" to mean "a long, obscure word". I don't recall ever hearing "75-cent word". I agree that without context, I'm not sure if that means a long word or a short word or something else entirely. (Personally, I think "quarter" is a 25-cent word. :-)

Comment: @Unreason: There are nearly 10 times more *50-cent words* than *75-cent words* in [google books](http://www.google.com/search?q="cent%20word"&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%2250-cent+word%22&pbx=1&oq=%2250-cent+word%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=60500l62047l3l62578l4l0l4l0l0l0l0l0ll3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e5731260b7cbe5c3&biw=1427&bih=920).

Comment: I first heard this as "25-cent word" about 8 years ago.

Comment: If you want to know the psychology of the particular instance, my initial statement was 'SAT word', which immediately sounded culturally narrow..then I thought '"50 cent word" or is it "75 cents", I don't know, 75 sounds that much better; I think I heard someone say that one time'. So, there you go. But it means what everyone thinks it does.

Comment: Which is to say that, on reflection, I believe '50 cent' is probably the more recognizable version.

Comment: It may have its roots in the phrase [half-crown word](http://books.google.com/books?id=VR1AAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22half%20crown%20word%22&pg=PA210#v=onepage&q=%22half%20crown%20word%22&f=false). Apparently Thomas Middleton alluded to the phrase in [A Chaste Maid in Cheapside](http://books.google.com/books?id=uianpaDIj60C&lpg=PA164&dq=%22half%20crown%20words%22&pg=PA164#v=onepage&q=%22half%20crown%20words%22&f=false) and Alan Watkins [used it almost four centuries later.](http://www.independent.co.uk/opinion/commentators/alan-watkins/these-daughters-of-rebekah-are-a-terrifying-spectacle-697009.html).

Comment: Lol! We always said " A 50 Cent Word ". was one of those words which was not in our vocabulary, mainly because we lacked the knowledge about the word. (eg; trite, antidisestablishmentarism). I'm a down to earth fella and never attended college, so I'm sure my vocabulary is lacking in what we called " fancy words" !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checking NGram for [cent word](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cent%20word&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it seems to me the most common usage is [Don't use a 50-cent word when a 5-cent one will do](http://books.google.com/books?id=HWc0S0251lMC&pg=PA36&dq=%22cent%20word%22&hl=en&ei=RAOfTpDmLIeY8QPy0fyRCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22cent%20word%22&f=false).

The earliest example I can find for a **50-cent word** is [Printers' ink, Volume 153, Issue 2 (1930)](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZYELAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cent%20word%22&dq=%22cent%20word%22&hl=en&ei=5wOfTuOeNMKU8gO8jJW1CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCA), where it's not contrasted with any higher/lower value word. But I think it's being used to identify an impressive-sounding new [buzzword](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buzzword), so I guess the speaker already knew the 50-5 saying.

Having invented the English language, we Brits think our words are beyond price anyway, so we don't have any monetary idioms for them. We do use [tuppenny-ha'penny](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cent%20word%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22tuppenny-ha%27penny%22&pbx=1&oq=%22tuppenny-ha%27penny%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=55203l67953l6l69297l29l27l0l0l0l6l235l3968l6.16.5l27l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e5731260b7cbe5c3&biw=1427&bih=920) and [ten-a-penny](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FaN_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22his%20ten%20a%20penny%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22his%20ten%20a%20penny%22&f=false)<sup>1</sup> for things that are cheap/low-quality, but there's no standard "high-price" version for expensive/good alternatives.

---

<sup>1</sup> cf US [two-bit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/two-bit) and [dime a dozen](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dime+a+dozen)

Comment: From [American Machinist, Vol. 13, No. 38 (1890)](http://books.google.com/books?id=VSFEAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22half%20dollar%20word%22&pg=RA5-PA26#v=onepage&q=%22half%20dollar%20word%22&f=false): "There has been far too much highfalutin by men who, to cover their own ignorance, have used long _half-dollar words_ to express what no fellow could understand."

Comment: @D Krueger: It goes back a fair way then. I can't help but suspect that a high-falutin' *half-dollar/50-cent word* implies ordinary ones were already proverbially cheaper. Perhaps initially they were a dime-a-dozen, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers for the research, and also for the insight on Brit mentality. Interesting that the phrase seems to be American-only...a commentary on American mentality, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of this expression was in the days of the telegraph. When you wanted to send a message over telegraph, you were charged per word. The larger the word, the higher the price. So, "fifty-cent word" (or whatever the monetary amount) referred to a word with many letters, probably the maximum price at the time.

As stated elsewhere, the implication is that a shorter, "cheaper" word would have worked just as well or better in the given context!

Comment: Wonderful false etymology. But actually, all words were the same price. This is why *the ABC universal commercial electric telegraphic codebook (fourth edition, 1899):* used codewords such as "municipal" for "must not be" and "murenger" for "you must".